# Can't make navbar links be displayed inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The navbar links show as block instead of inline even though I'm using `<div style="display: inline-block;">` as seen in another post here

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Navbar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Navbar</h1>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 mr-0 px-3" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
        <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't need any extra CSS to make them inline.. the links aren't in the right structure and there is no navbar-expand class. [Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/) and use the [correct navbar structure](https://www.codeply.com/p/nA84F3WCi7)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the parent div of your navbar links **is inline**, so I assume you're referring to the links themselves appearing on top of each other instead of side-by-side. To fix this, simply apply the same styling you used on the parent to the links themselves.

Here are two ways of solving this depending on if you would prefer a solution in the HTML file or in an external CSS file. **It is not necessary to include both solutions.**

```html
<a style="display: inline-block" class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
<a style="display: inline-block" class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
```

```css
li > .nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It does not work. Did you try it on my snippet?

Comment: Yes, I ran it both on codepen and in the stackoverflow compiler. Make sure you are setting the individual anchor tags to have display: inline-block, this is the key you were missing in your submitted code.